# Delete items from list of list

Tags: python

This is my original array:

```
b = [[], [1], [22, 132], [3, 123], [], [], [6], [], [], [89]]
```

This is what i want:

```
b = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: `b = [[] for x in b]`

Comment: deleting removes the entire list object. if you want them to be empty, set them to `''`

Comment: yeah it will store 10 elements but now i want to remove all the elements so that i can put another set of numbers to it .

Comment: I want to do store like this 
b = [[], [1], [22, 132], [3, 123], [], [], [6], [], [], [89]]
b = [[13], [], [34,25], [], [], [], [12,13,17], [], [], [7]]
but i cant treat it as a list    
coz it will delete all the elements and give the length of b as 1

Comment: @DanielLee-still i ain't getting

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you for pointing that out. Deleted my buggy tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over `b`, either setting each element to the empty list or deleting the contents of that element:

```
for i in xrange(len(b)):
  b[i] = []
```

or

```
for i in xrange(len(b)):
  del b[i][:]
```

Comment: Why the use of an index? `for sublist in b: del sublist[:]` would work just fine.

Comment: This is what i needed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's much better